# dotNetInstaller with output MSI file

Tags: wix, dotnetinstaller

I have an application, which can be installed via MSI package. Right now I need to extend this package to check if .NET 4.0 is installed. I want to use dotNetInstaller, but I can't change name and extention of file (dotNetInstaller creates an exe file). Is it possible to create file with MSI extention?

Answer (score 0):

If you targeted your project for .net 4 in the project-setting the standard MSI-installer from that project would check for such a dependency and would provide the user with a solution to fullfill the dependency on setup but only if you havn't scrued with the standard-settings. (There are checkboxes to disable such a behavoir) You can also add additional dependencies to check for at setup time.

Comment: I use WiX and don't see have to check .NET 4 without bootstrapper